# How to find out that some generic class are defined?

Tags: c++, generics, hash, hashtable

I trying to implement generic hash table and i need to ensure that there is a defined hash function for this generic type.

Something like this

```cpp
template<typename T>
class HashTable{
    public:
    HashTable(){
        static_assert(is_defined<hash<T>>(),
                  "There is no implementation for hash<T> ...");
        //...
    }
    //...
};
```

How i should implement `is_defined` method or how should i replace it?

Comment: SFINAE is the first which come in mind.